# How to deal with questions that turn out to be a result of the user overlooking something?

Tags: discussion, best-practice

Let's say a user asks a question and that question is because of an error on the user's part. Here is an example:

- [Missed snapshot tab in virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191294/missed-snapshot-tab-in-virtualbox)

Another example is when one asks a question like *Can't find the Firefox preference tab*. But then later on, the user finds the Firefox preference tab and answers the question 
himself. I've seen a lot of these questions over the past couple  of months.

So, my question is, does these type of questions need to be deleted because it's a "user error" (no coffee / simply overlooked / 10 hours straight programming, brain is fried!, etc)?

Comment: Ok so i can vote to close them myself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we close those questions as "Too localized" as they are not particularly helpful to the larger audience.

> **Too localized**
>
> This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;
> it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in
> time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally
> applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet. For help making
> this question more broadly applicable, see the FAQ.

You can flag those questions for closure when and where necessary.

---

See also:

- [What does each flag reason mean, and when should I use them?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3520/what-does-each-flag-reason-mean-and-when-should-i-use-them)