# How to mark question as duplicate? What happens when I click on flag?

Tags: support, flagging, duplicates, flags

I was hesitant to rampantly flag a question (which I considered a duplicate), because I feared this would automatically disrepute the question and/or - even worse - the question-asker. So,

- How to mark question as **duplicate**?
- What happens when I click on **flag**?

Answer (score 5):

I found these meta questions:

- [What does each flag reason mean, and when should I use them?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3520/what-does-each-flag-reason-mean-and-when-should-i-use-them)
- [Where on earth is the "mark duplicate" UI?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118124/where-on-earth-is-the-mark-as-duplicate-ui-on-stack-overflow)

Only then did I know where and how to proceed (with marking the question as a **duplicate**).

Thus:

1. right below the question click on **flag**
2. read-what-it-says-on-the-tin *:-D*

Comment: I also leave a comment saying something like: "Possible Duplicate" and then a link to the duplicate.  This way if its _not_ a duplicate the OP can point out why.

Comment: Yep, that's also what I did first.