# Flagging a post

Tags: discussion

I've been banned for flagging a post for 7 days because 4 of my flagging were not appropriate,I know Moderators  are very busy People and It creates an extra load on them. What should I know before flagging a post because there were post which were not absolutely understandable?Do people who are not very much sound technically should review posts on AskUbuntu? And On all the flags I already see that some gentleman has considered it a spam? Where as I flag only for low quality or not an answer.I had a total history of flagging 322 out of which 255 are helpful?Some answers are edited now.

https://askubuntu.com/users/flag-summary/370150

Like the last answer in post [Image viewer WebM compatible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714136/image-viewer-webm-compatible/750304#750304) by @dmitriy just edited and bit modified  by me earlier I flagged it as a low quality post?

Comment: Can you link some of the posts that you flagged that were rejected and what reason you flagged them as? It would help to understand what happend.

Comment: @markkirby This is all my flagging history

Comment: Only mods can see your flagging history, so the link is useless for us.

Comment: @muru is right, you need to link questions and say why you flagged them and why they were rejected or we can't help you.

Comment: @markkirby   See one post which is not edited

Comment: OK, I see why you would flag that. What did you flag it as?

Comment: @markkirby now the answer is making sense after editing

Comment: @markkirby I just edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/714136/image-viewer-webm-compatible/750304#750304) was declined because even though it is a low-quality post, it still offers a solution. It's not a great answer, but it is an answer. Moderator flags are for truly bad content, not low-quality.

[Here](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3520/what-does-each-flag-reason-mean-and-when-should-i-use-them) are some (older, but still accurate) explanations of what each flag means.